# lodash mapValues async

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Inside _.mapValues I want get some modified values with some latency (for example from DB), but I was faced with problem: while I modify values in sync mode everything is good, when i try use promises or callback its work incorrectly (in first case I get Promise object, in second: undefined value).
Here some simplified example, how i can rewrite code inside mapValues to solve this problem?

```
'use strict';
const _ = require('lodash');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

let obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
};

let increment = (value) => {
  return value + 1;
};

let incrementProm = (value) => {
  return Promise.resolve(value + 1);
};

let incrementCb = (value, cb) => {
  let res = value + 1;
  let err = null;
  setTimeout(cb.bind(undefined, err, res), 100);
};

let t1 = _.mapValues(obj, (value) => {
  return increment(value);
});

let t2 = _.mapValues(obj, (value) => {
  return incrementProm(value);
});

let t3 = _.mapValues(obj, (value) => {
  let temp;
  incrementCb(value, (err, res) => {
    temp = res;
  });
  return temp;
});

console.log('Sync res:');
console.log(t1);
console.log('Promise res:');
console.log(t2);
console.log('Callback res:');
console.log(t3);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bluebird's [props()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.props.html) function to resolve all properties with promises.

```
Promise.props(_.mapValues(obj, incrementProm))
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

```js
var obj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2
};

var incrementProm = value => Promise.resolve(value + 1);

Promise.props(_.mapValues(obj, incrementProm))
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.4.1/bluebird.js"></script>
```

Comment: take note that `Promise.props()` is specific to Bluebird promises. If you're using native (or any other implementation), you're going to have to find another way

Answer (score 2):

You're mapping onto promises, so something I do might be:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
let incrementProm = (value) => {
  return Promise.resolve(value + 1);
};

let obj = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
}

let keys = _.keys(obj);
let promises = _.map(keys, k => {
    return incrementProm(obj[k])
    .then(newValue => { return { key: k, value: newValue } });
})
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    values.forEach(v => obj[v.key] = v.value)
})
.then(() => {
    // now your object is updated: foo = 2 and bar = 3
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement an async version of mapValues. Something like...

```js
async function mapValuesAsync(object, asyncFn) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(object).map(async ([key, value]) => [
        key,
        await asyncFn(value, key, object)
      ])
    )
  );
}
```

Then call it like you would call `_.mapValues`:

```js
let t2 = await mapValuesAsync(obj, (value) => {
    return incrementProm(value);
});
```

or, simply

```js
let t2 = await mapValuesAsync(obj, incrementProm);
```

Comment: this is a very elegant solution, but only works with es2019 or later

Answer (score 2):

Here's a **TypeScript** solution, built on top of **lodash** functions:

```js
import { fromPairs, toPairs, ObjectIterator } from 'lodash';

export async function mapValuesAsync<T extends object, TResult>(
  obj: T | null | undefined,
  callback: ObjectIterator<T, Promise<TResult>>,
): Promise<{ [P in keyof T]: TResult }> {
  return fromPairs(
    await Promise.all(
      toPairs(obj).map(async ([key, value]) => [
        key,
        await callback(value, key, obj),
      ]),
    ),
  ) as { [P in keyof T]: TResult };
}
```

If you don't need types, here's the **JavaScript** version:

```js
import { fromPairs, toPairs } from 'lodash';

export async function mapValuesAsync(obj, callback) {
  return fromPairs(
    await Promise.all(
      toPairs(obj).map(async ([key, value]) => [
        key,
        await callback(value, key, obj),
      ]),
    ),
  );
}
```

And here's a test, just in case you need it:

```js
import { mapValuesAsync } from './map-values-async';

describe('mapValuesAsync', () => {
  it('should map values with an async callback', async () => {
    const result = await mapValuesAsync(
      {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
      },
      async (value) => {
        return await Promise.resolve(value * 2);
      },
    );

    const expected = {
      a: 2,
      b: 4,
    };
    expect(result).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

This is inspired by [Rui Castro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2602440/rui-castro)'s response, posted above, which elegantly makes use of `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`. However, that requires es2019 or later to work. Lodash has equivalent functions, `toPairs` and `fromPairs`, which work with any flavour of JavaScript.